# When dtype conversion fails, return NaN with pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to avoid this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'blablabla'

When I read in a csv I want to specify that column X should be an `int` or a `float64`.
If any value in column X cannot be converted, then it should be assigned a null value.

How do I do this?

Comment: read in your df, then `df1=pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')`

Comment: So you're saying I have to `read_csv` every column as dtype `object` first? And *then* convert?

Comment: Also how do I challenge this duplicate question claim? The question @jpp linked says nothing about `read_csv`.

Comment: @timwiz, See the second duplicate. Bottom line is you are asking for functionality that doesn't exist. *All* the answers (and there are dozens of duplicates of your question) are the same.

Comment: "To save people w/ the same problem from goin thru docs"... It is understood and best practice that before you post a question on StackOverflow you have thoroughly investigated the documentation. It may not be common practice, but we actually want you to dive deep into the docs prior to posting a question, as many times simple cases like this could be resolved. This is perpetuating low quality questions on StackOverflow. In the future if you want to be a positive contributor, please don't post before reading documentation regarding your problem.

Comment: @d_kennetz I agree you should do research before asking a Q (I did).  Usually while programming, if I have a question, I simply google the question and voila! the answer appears (along w/ some good discussion). And yes this saves me the trouble of going back through docs that are often less easy to read. This is one of the beauties of SO. If you don't find the answer on SO, that means it's hopefully easy to find elsewhere (e.g. docs). If it's NOT easy to find elsewhere, congratulations: you've got the makings of a good question!

Comment: @d_kennetz This time around I googled the question. The answer I was looking for was not found. Then I went to the docs. The functionality I was looking for was not found (as a pampered R user I assumed it existed). So, I formulated a question in hopes that 1. I’d get an answer. 2. Other people could benefit from this answer (see above comment about Googling Qs). Unfortunately, the question was closed b4 the answer was provided and now it seems the reasonable comment refuting the closing was deleted.

Comment: I do agree that the unfortunate reality of this is that "mis-googling" something may not lead you to an adequate Q/A even when it exists. I have been there myself. Your question was ambiguous in accomplishing dtype conversion. To you it may have seemed like you wanted to explicitly change dtype only in the read_csv command, and not after. But to users (obviously myself and jpp), that your question was asking "If read_csv fails to convert dtype, then how do I do this" which has clear answers on the dup targets.

Comment: I agree that there are not excellent targets to point out that .read_csv() does not coerce errors when changing modifying dtype. This information has to be inferred from the targets, which can be misleading. My advice would be to delete this and if you feel strongly about it, open it up as a new question. Include dup targets in your question and specifically point out that none of these explicitly explain that you cannot `read_csv(infile, dtype=)` if errors exist in columns.You might get hit with a dup hammer again though. Just speculation.

Comment: @d_kennetz Thanks very much for taking the time to explain these thoughts. I'll try to be more specific and include prior research next time.